# Captcha don't change with new version of GWAN

Tags: debian, g-wan

Why this page `captcha.c` isn't changing with the new version of `gwan` ? (the picture doesn't change)

This example worked fine in older versions!

Comment: What picture?     what code are you talking about?

Comment: The code on the web server page "captcha.c" in G-WAN don't work in the new version ! (sorry for my english..im french)

Comment: The **getns()** bug proved to be a compiler optimization that bypassed the calculations (other calls like getus() and getms() work fine). getns() has been fixed in v4.21 which will probably be published today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

That's right.

But the `httpdate.c` example is working as expected (changing each time you invoke it) so this is not a cache issue.

I have dropped a line to G-WAN's team, maybe you could have done that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Marek is right, other image generators work (`data_uri.c`, `fractal.c`, `charts.c`, etc.).

The `captcha.c` servlet is the only one to use the PRNG, which initialization remains constant in this example (hence constant results). You can see that in the code by adding a `printf()`:

```
   u32 seed = (u32)getns();
   prnd_t rnd; // pseudo-random generator (period: 1 << 158)
   sw_init(&rnd, seed); // EPOCH time in nano-seconds

   printf("seed:%u, sw_rnd:%u getns():%lu\n", seed, sw_rand(&rnd), getns());
```

The seed is always null because the result of `getns()` is constant (that's obviously a bug):

```
seed:0, sw_rnd:4048109956 getns():1358679437704429568
seed:0, sw_rnd:4048109956 getns():1358679437704429568
seed:0, sw_rnd:4048109956 getns():1358679437704429568
...
```

BTW, this is a good example of what a programmer is supposed to find by himself (and report to the program authors).

Comment: The bug was a compiler optimization which bypassed the calculation.